# dynamic declaration/query in oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00932

In Oracle, given a list of table names, I want to perform 'select column1 into var1 from table' statements on a mass number of tables. And I want to do this for all columns of a table. I cannot declare the type of var1 until the query with user_tab_columns returns the column's type. I tried to declare var1 as sys.anytype but got ORA-00932 with error message such as "inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got CHAR".

So how can I get past this error or how can I dynamically declare a variable? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Craig is right you should probably declare it as a VARCHAR2 instad of an anytype.

[This article](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/SQL/SQL_11.shtml) by Jeff Hunter has a nice function that makes this easy to populate your variable in way that won't break if your data can't be converted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getData(data IN SYS.ANYDATA)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    AS
      l_varchar2   VARCHAR2(4000);
      l_rc         NUMBER;
    BEGIN

      CASE data.getTypeName
        when 'SYS.NUMBER' then
          l_rc := data.getNumber(l_varchar2);
        when 'SYS.DATE' then
          l_rc := data.getDate(l_varchar2);
        when 'SYS.VARCHAR2' then
          l_rc := data.getVarchar2(l_varchar2);
        else
          l_varchar2 := '** unknown **';
      END CASE;

      RETURN l_varchar2;

    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Most datatypes will implicitly convert into a VARCHAR.  Obviously there are exceptions, but if your tables are just varchars, dates, and numbers then you should be fine.